# Get update data in cart with checkout_cart_update_items_before event

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer

I tried to get the update data when cart item qty is updated. I used event `checkout_cart_update_items_before` because i want to check it before the item updated. How can i get the update data?

**Example data i want to take :**

```
 1. Item A change qty from 10 to 5.
 2. Item B change qty from 1 to 3.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data parameters of the same event `checkout_cart_update_items_before` to get the desired result.

There are two parameters being dispatched with this event. One is the actual cart object and the second one holds the updated data.

Both objects have a relationship based on quote item id. You can use that to get your result like below.

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_update_items_before">
        <observer name="update_item_before" instance="{Namespace}\{Module}\Observer\UpdateCartItem" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/Observer/UpdateCartItem.php

```
<?php
namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Observer;

class UpdateCartItem implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getItems();
        $info = $observer->getInfo()->getData();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
             echo 'Item '. $item->getName() .' change qty from ' . $item->getQty() . ' to ' . $info[$item->getId()]['qty'] . '.<br>';
        }
    }
}
```